# GeoJSON layer development

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I would like to draw war control lines, and am trying to find a way to export umap or other control zones to GeoJSON.

What possible tools could I use to do that, and what geo-polygon tools would allow me to make more delicate control lines?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! Please add more details to your question. Also, please have in mind that questions should address a specific GIS-related problem. As currently written, your question is to "open" to be answered. "What would work best" would lead to opinion-based answers. So please provide us with specific information about what you have tried so far and what you plan to do exactly.

Comment: Yessir @winnewoerp

Comment: @winnewoerp Is that better? I am still learning how best to use these sites.

Comment: please take the [tour] to find out how our site works

Comment: So you want to draw the control lines in uMap for example, export them to GeoJSON and use the GeoJSON vector data in your own Leaflet map?

Comment: @winnewoerp Yes, pretty much.

Comment: I posted an answer and I hope that it helps you. However, please have in mind that this site is mainly used for problems that can't be solved even after searching for solutions all over the web. Answers are not supposed to be a "Beginner's guide" for the respective tools. There are much better sources on the web for the "first steps".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Exporting GeoJSON from uMap is explained here](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/UMap/Guide/Export_data_of_my_uMap) in the OpenStreetMap Wiki.

[image: Export options in uMap (Source: OpenStreetMap Wiki)]
*(image source: OSM Wiki)*

Select "geojson" instead of "Full map data" in the download section.

The simplest way of [using GeoJSON with Leaflet is presented here](https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/) in the Leaflet examples section.  Copy & paste the contents of your GeoJSON into the `geojsonFeature` variable.

```
let geojsonFeature = {
    /* your GeoJSON goes here */
};
```

If you want to load the data from the file instead of directly pasting the GeoJSON code you can use the [Leaflet AJAX plugin](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet-ajax):

```
let geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("path/to/your/geojsonfile.json");
```